# Condition for a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a number which can be expressed as follows:

\begin{align}
y=\sqrt{(4m\left(k+1\right)+1)^2-(4m*k)^2}
\end{align}

with $k$ and $m$ being any positive integers. I would like to know under what values of $m$ written in terms of $k$ can this expression have integral solutions?

Comment: Done! Sorry for the mistake, had forgotten a curly brace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring you get that
$$y^2=(4mk+4m+1)^2-(4mk)^2$$
Now if $y\in\mathbb{N}$ then $y^2\in\mathbb{N}$, so we just need that
$$(4mk+4m+1)^2-(4mk)^2=x^2\text{ where } x\in\mathbb{N}$$
Simplifying gives
$$(4mk+4m+1)^2-(4mk)^2=(8mk+4m+1)(4m+1)$$
So either
$$8mk+4m+1=4m+1\implies m=0$$
or
$$(1)\,\,8mk+4m+1=x^2 \text{ and } (2)\,\,4m+1=y^2 \text{ where } x,y\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$\text{From }(2)\,\,y\equiv 1,3\mod{4}$$
$$m = \frac{(1+4a)^2-1}4=4a^2+2a=2a(2a+1)\text{ for } a\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$m = \frac{(3+4b)^2-1}4=4b^2+6b+2=(2b+1)(2b+2)=2c(2c-1)\text{ for } b,c\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$\text{From } (1)\,\,x\equiv1,3 \mod{4}$$
$$m=\frac{(1+4d)^2-1}{8k+4}=\frac{2d(2d+1)}{2k+1}=2k \,\,(\text{by letting }d=k) \text{ for } d\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$m=\frac{(3+4e)^2-1}{8k+4}=\frac{(2e+1)(2e+2)}{2k+1}=2(k+1) \,\,(\text{by letting }e=k) \text{ for } e\in\mathbb{N}$$
So in order for this to be an integer we need that
$$\boxed{m=2k\text{ or } 2(k+1)}$$
such that
$$\boxed{k=x(2x+1) \text{ or } x(2x-1) \text{ for } x\in\mathbb{N}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, Peter. I have arrived at the same solution as you $m=2k$ and otherwise,  but I do not know how to get the other solutions in the space. What I mean is: assume $k=6$, then $y$ is an integer when $m=12$, but also for cases like $m=462$, $m=54990$ or in the case where $k=33$, the solution is $m=600$, which is a bit odd! So, how do I get the other possible solutions?

Comment: It comes down to the fact that $m=\frac{2d(2d+1)}{2k+1}$ has the solution $d=k$ for integer $m$, but there are infinitely many solutions omitted when for example $k=1$ and $d\equiv0\mod{3}$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Could you please be kind enough to demonstrate it for $k=33$ case? Thanks!

Comment: I'm just saying that I don't think you can generalise every case such as with $k=33$ because there are so many different variables involved. I have just provided a formula to find infinitely many solutions, but they are all of a certain form.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter! With $y$ forced to be an integer, with a given $k$, is it possible to derive an expression for $m$ in terms of $k$? Something like a Chinese remainder theorem? It means that $4m+1$ and $8mk+4m+1$ should be perfect squares following your answer. I don't know how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

Above equation shown below has parameterization:

$y^2=(4mk+4m+1)^2-(4mk)^2$

Taking, $m=2k$, we get $y^2=(4k+1)^2(8k+1)=(4k+1)^2(w)^2$

Hence we need to make, $(8k+1)=w^2$

Take $k=[(21p^2-26p+8)/(p)^2]$ & $w=[(13p-8)/(p)]$

For, $p=2$ we get $(w,k,m,y)=(9,10,20,369)$

For, $p=4$, we get $(w,k,m,y)=(11,15,30,671)$

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for the reply. This solution is nice, but how did you arrive at the peculiar solutions for $k$ and $w$?